# Laravel 7.24 How can I change the colour of the Navigation bar if a user logs in

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have a **pseudo dynamic** navigation bar, which changes its colour when a user **logs in**. This color change should happen, no matter where the user roams inside the pages (Home page, contact us page etc.),as long as the user is authenticated. Can someone give some ideas?

It need not be multiple colours. Like before the user logs in, it is black. After the user logs in, it changes to blue

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
       <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
           <li class="nav-item active">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="contact">Contact Us</a>
           </li>
       </ul>
       <ul class="navbar-nav">
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="login">Login</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link"href="new_user">Signup</a>
           </li>
       </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You can use `auth()->check()` in your view to determine whether the user is logged in or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
@if (auth()->check()) {{-- or Auth::check() --}}
  //show logged in stuff
@else
  //show logged out stuff
@endif
```

Your code would look like

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark @if(auth()->check()) bg-blue @else bg-black @endif">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
       <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
           <li class="nav-item active">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="contact">Contact Us</a>
           </li>
       </ul>
       <ul class="navbar-nav">
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="login">Login</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link"href="new_user">Signup</a>
           </li>
       </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was actually using that `@if(Auth::check()) ` for the the entire `div` element, which would have made the pages slow.

Answer (score 3):

you should better use a helper function if you want it to be customizable again easily. for that:

1. make a `helper.php` file in `app` folder
2. put your code inside like this

   ```
   <?php

   function getNavigationColor()
   {
      if (auth()->check()){
          return 'bg-color-black';
      else{
          return 'bg-color-blue';
      }
   }
   ```
3. edit `composer.json` add line below at the end of `autoload`

   ```
   "autoload": {
       //... other params
       "files":[
           "app/helpers.php"
       ]
   },
   ```
4. run `composer du` in commandline

now you can access getNavigationColor() everywhere in your project.

then use it every where you want like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark {{ getNavigationColor() }}">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
       <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
           <li class="nav-item active">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="contact">Contact Us</a>
           </li>
       </ul>
       <ul class="navbar-nav">
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="login">Login</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link"href="new_user">Signup</a>
           </li>
       </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you did, or give me the link to the official documentation of this concept? I don't know about it- like  `composer du`

Comment: it is some thing like helper function of laravel. for example ```auth()``` function that you can call it every where in your project. when you add your file to composer auto load you say to composer that you want that file from start of project and after that you have to dump and load composer again to make composer does what you changed in ```composer.json``` file the full command is ```composer dump-autoload``` but the short form is ```composer du``` i do it in all of my projects and it is very clean i put all of functions that i want to use in blades in that.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your solution but it threw some error message

Comment: `Call to undefined function getNavigationColor() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\LaraTest\resources\views\contact_us.blade.php)`

Comment: Yes. It did work. But the error message still showed in browser

Comment: add your ```composer.json``` file

Comment: I formatted my laptop and accidentally deleted the folder. Although I backed up the files, I need to modify them a bit.

Comment: Here are the images-https://ibb.co/9YcsPfL ibb.co/SQhqLh7

Answer (score 1):

You can use laravel blade directives to make this task simpler.

use @auth directive for authenticated user and @guest directive for guest user.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark @auth bg-blue @endauth @guest bg-black @endguest ">
```